# Possibilities for $[K^{sep}:K]$

Tags: field-theory

I use the notation $K^{sep}$ to denote the separable closure of a field $K$ and $\bar{K}$ for the algebraic closure, that is

$$K^{sep}:=\{\alpha \in \bar{K} \mid \alpha \text{ is separable over } K\}.$$ It's a somewhat non-trivial fact that $K^{sep}$ is a field. In the case that the base field is perfect then $K^{sep} = \bar{K}$. In particular if $K$ is a perfect field this is answered by the Artin-Schreier theorem which tells us that $[\bar{K}:{K}]=1,2$ or $\infty$. If $K$ is an inseparable field of characteristic $p$ what are the possibilities for $[K^{sep}:K]$? I've thought about this some, but I don't have a good working knowledge of imperfect fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The degree of $[K^{sep}:K]$ must be either 1 or $\infty$, according to [Theorem 4.1 of this article](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/artinschreier.pdf).

Comment: I've been meaning to work through that note of Conrad's for awhile and haven't gotten around to working all the way through. Thanks.